# Can't use okhttp with com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, picasso, okhttp, image-loading

My problem is quite a complex one and not sure what might fix it. I am using picasso:2.5.2 to download images from urls to load into my listview items. I was using the combination of okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0 and okhttp:2.2.0 to use with Picasso. Image loading was fast and all the images were loading (including redirects).

I integrated com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads yesterday in project and it does not allow okhttp to be declared in library and declares okio as duplicate files.

Now as I can't declare okhttp in gradle file, Picasso only shows few images and that too very slow. Will upload Gradle and other files if needed for analysis.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer yes i understand but i went through all the QnAs and i didnt find the answer. could you guide me to correct path on it .